# How do set REDIS + APC

Tags: redis, apc

How do set REDIS with APC in magento (local.xml)?

I have to put twice the "< backend >"?

My code looks like this:

```
<cache>
   <backend>apc</backend>
    <slow_backend>file</slow_backend>
    <slow_backend_store_data>0</slow_backend_store_data>
    <auto_refresh_fast_cache>1</auto_refresh_fast_cache>
    <lifetime>259200</lifetime>
    <prefix>database_</prefix>

  <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
  <backend_options>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server>
    <port>6379</port>
    <persistent></persistent>
    <database>0</database>
    <password></password>
    <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
    <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
    <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
    <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
    <compress_data>1</compress_data>
    <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
    <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
    <compression_lib>lzf</compression_lib>
  </backend_options>
</cache>
```

Comment: donot use APC, install ZendOpcache, and keep it only for php, and use Redis only for cache.

Answer (score 0):

You cant set both as cache backend.
But you could chose one as normal backend, and one as slow backend where you currently have `file`.

I think redis was suited as slow one, but iam not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

APC is great for OPCode, terrible for data key pair storage. APC should be working as-is with no need to add it to `local.xml` for handling the cache of PHP's OPcode.

Only one backend handler is allowed, while slow/fast backend types would fall under this branch in the xml tree.

```
<config>
<global>
    <session_save><![CDATA[]]></session_save> <!-- db / memcache / empty=files -->
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[]]></session_save_path><!-- e.g. for memcache session save handler tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10 -->
    <session_cache_limiter><![CDATA[]]></session_cache_limiter><!-- see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php#82174 for possible values -->
    <cache>
        <backend></backend><!-- apc / memcached / xcache / empty=file -->
        <slow_backend></slow_backend> <!-- database / file (default) - used for 2 levels cache setup, necessary for all shared memory storages -->
        <slow_backend_store_data></slow_backend_store_data> <!-- 1 / 0 (default) - used for 2 levels cache setup, sets whether store data in db slow cache backend -->
        <auto_refresh_fast_cache></auto_refresh_fast_cache> <!-- 1 / 0 (default) - used for 2 levels cache setup, sets whether refresh data in fast cache backend -->
        <memcached><!-- memcached cache backend related config -->
            <servers><!-- any number of server nodes can be included -->
                <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[]]></persistent>
                    <weight><![CDATA[]]></weight>
                    <timeout><![CDATA[]]></timeout>
                    <retry_interval><![CDATA[]]></retry_interval>
                    <status><![CDATA[]]></status>
                </server>
            </servers>
            <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
            <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
            <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
            <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
            <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
        </memcached>
    </cache>

    <!-- example of two level cache setup with slow backend at files. -->
    <full_page_cache>
        <backend_options>
             <cache_dir>full_page_cache</cache_dir>
         </backend_options>
         <slow_backend_options>
             <hashed_directory_level>1</hashed_directory_level>
             <hashed_directory_umask>0777</hashed_directory_umask>
             <file_name_prefix>fpc</file_name_prefix>
             <cache_dir><![CDATA[full_page_cache]]></cache_dir>
         </slow_backend_options>
     </full_page_cache>

    <remote_addr_headers><!-- list headers that contain real client IP if webserver is behind a reverse proxy -->
        <header1>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header1>
        <header2>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header2>
    </remote_addr_headers>
</global>
```

A good example `local.xml` from:

- [Optimizing app/etc/local.xml - caching like Redis](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/28818/69)

Further reading:

- http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/